# LINQ Group & Sum on a list of Models where a property is another model

Tags: c#, linq, model, group-by, aggregate

I havent been able to find any answers to this specific question on LINQ Group & Aggregation so am hoping someone here can help. I have a list of models of such:

```
public class BasketProduct
{
    public ProductItem  Product { get; set; }
    public int          Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal      SubTotal { get; set; }
    public DateTime     DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

where the first property is another model:

```
public class ProductItem
{
    public int      ID { get; set; }
    public string   Description { get; set; }
    public char     Item { get; set; }
    public decimal  Price { get; set; }
    public string   ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string   Barcode { get; set; }
}
```

I basically want to be able to Group and Aggregate on this list:

```
List<BasketProduct> allBasketProducts =
```

Using the following:

```
        allBasketProducts = allBasketProducts
            .GroupBy(x => x.Product.ID)
            .Select(y => new BasketProduct
                                        {
                                            Product.ID = y.First().Product.ID,
                                            Product.Item = y.First().Product.Item,
                                            Product.Description = y.First().Product.Description,
                                            Quantity = y.Sum(z => z.Quantity),
                                            Product.ImagePath = y.First().Product.ImagePath,
                                            Product.Price = y.First().Product.Price,
                                            SubTotal = y.Sum(z => z.SubTotal)
                                        }).ToList();
```

However it seriously doesn't like this (as per red squigly lines and even red'er text):

[image]

Can someone help please?

Comment: I don't think you need the `select` part. But I might be misunderstanding the requirement. Can you explain what exactly should be the result?

Comment: What is/are the error/s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue isn't actually related to LINQ, it's your `ProductItem` constructor. You need to construct its nested `Product` object explicitly, like this:

```
allBasketProducts
    .GroupBy(x => x.Product.ID)
    .Select(y => new BasketProduct
        {
            Quantity = y.Sum(z => z.Quantity),
            SubTotal = y.Sum(z => z.SubTotal),
            Product = new ProductItem
            {
                ID = y.First().Product.ID,
                Item = y.First().Product.Item,
                Description = y.First().Product.Description,
                ImagePath = y.First().Product.ImagePath,
                Price = y.First().Product.Price
            }
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var totals = 
    (from b in allBasketProducts
    group new { b.Quantity, b.SubTotal, Product= b.Product } by b.Product.ID into g
    select new BasketProduct
    { 
        Product = g.First().Product,
        SubTotal = g.Sum(z => z.SubTotal), 
        Quantity = g.Sum(z => z.Quantity)
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            allBasketProducts = allBasketProducts  
             .GroupBy(x => x.Product.ID)
             .Select(y => new BasketProduct()
             {
                 Product = new ProductItem() {
                     ID = y.First().Product.ID,
                     Item = y.First().Product.Item,
                     Description = y.First().Product.Description,
                     ImagePath = y.First().Product.ImagePath,
                     Price = y.First().Product.Price
                 },
                 Quantity = y.Sum(z => z.Quantity),
                 SubTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the type of your `Select`, the compiler expects only the properties of that type. So you can only set the properties `Product`,  `Subtotal`, `Quantity` and `DateAdded` in that code of yours.

You can find the Product simply by selecting the first Product that has an ID that matches your grouping Key:

```
var allBasketProductsGroupedByProductID = allBasketProducts
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Product.ID)
                        .Select(y => new BasketProduct
                        {
                            Product = y.First(i => i.Product.ID == y.Key).Product,
                            Quantity = y.Sum(z => z.Quantity),
                            SubTotal = y.Sum(z => z.SubTotal)                   
                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
  List allBasketProducts = new List();

```
        allBasketProducts = new List<BasketProduct>()
        {
            new BasketProduct()
            {
                Product = new ProductItem()
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    Price = 5,
                },
                Quantity = 2,
                SubTotal = 2,

            },

            new BasketProduct()
            {
                Product = new ProductItem()
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    Price = 5,
                },
                Quantity = 4,
                SubTotal = 2,

            },
            new BasketProduct()
            {
                Product = new ProductItem()
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    Price = 10,
                },
                Quantity = 3,
                SubTotal = 2,

            },
            new BasketProduct()
            {
                Product = new ProductItem()
                {
                    ID = 3,
                    Price = 20,
                },
                Quantity = 3,
                SubTotal = 2,

            },
            new BasketProduct()
            {
                Product = new ProductItem()
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    Price = 20,
                },
                Quantity = 3,
                SubTotal = 2,

            }
        };

        allBasketProducts = allBasketProducts
            .GroupBy(x => x.Product.ID)
            .Select(y => new BasketProduct()
            {
                Product = new ProductItem()
                {
                    ID = y.First().Product.ID,
                    Item = y.First().Product.Item,
                    Description = y.First().Product.Description,
                    ImagePath = y.First().Product.ImagePath,
                    Price = y.First().Product.Price
                },
                Quantity = y.Sum(z => z.Quantity),
                SubTotal = y.Sum(z => z.SubTotal)
            }).ToList();
```